# ¿Hay una forma de utilizar populate() dentro de la información que se ha traído con otro populate?

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

**Mi consulta originalmente trae esto**:

```
{
    "payload": {
        "_id": "622a12390c6e374f5427754c",
        "idOffices": "621786b0582c3f4d68107d67",
    }
}
```

**por medio de populate al campo *idOffices* obtengo esto:**

```
"payload": {
        "_id": "622a12390c6e374f5427754c",
        "idOffices": {
            "_id": "621786b0582c3f4d68107d67",
            "idVenues": "621650a2bac1f704507c7474",
            "office": "Prueba",
            "floor": 10,
            "capacity": 154,
            "status": true,
            "createdAt": "2022-02-24T13:22:56.591Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-02-24T13:22:56.591Z"
        },
    }
```

**La pregunta es: ¿hay alguna forma de utilizar `populate` en el campo *idVenues* y que traiga la info de esa collección, aunque ese campo no esté en el schema?**

Este es mi Schema

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document, SchemaTypes, Types } from 'mongoose';

export type sitesDocument = SitesSchemas & Document;

@Schema({ versionKey: false, timestamps: true })
export class SitesSchemas {

  @Prop({type:SchemaTypes.ObjectId, required:true, ref:'Offices._id'})
  idOffices:Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  capacity: number;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  status: boolean;
}
export const sitesSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(SitesSchemas);
export const sitesCollection = {
  name: 'sites',
  collection: 'Sites',
  schema: sitesSchema,

};
```

Como el campo *idVenues* lo obtengo con `populate()` no lo incluí en el schema.

Answer (score 0):

Para traer nested collections puedes checar la documentación de Mongoose en [este apartado](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate).

Pero básicamente tendrías que ejecutar el query de esta manera:

```
PayloadModel.findOne({id})
.populate({
    path: 'idOffices',
    populate: { path: 'idVenues' }
 });
```

Pregunta: La última parte de tu post dice que idVenues no está en el Schema de idOffices. Por qué idVenues no estaría en el Schema de idOffices? Incluye idVenues en el Schema de idOffices. Si algunas idOffices no necesitan ese campo, el campo simplemente no se rellenará.

Comment: Disculpa, creo que le falto algo a mi pregunta, estoy usando una colección llamada sites y es ahí donde hago el populate() para obtener IdOffices y con eso obtengo idVenues, lo que intento hacer es hacer un populate() sobre el idVenues que obtuve desde el primer Populate(). Gracias